# nameless char[] to std::string& reference

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

Is it okay to pass nameless `char[]` to function with `std::string&` parameter?

```
#include <string>

void func(std::string&);

int main()
{
  func("nameless");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not OK in your example, because you use a non-const lvalue reference. A temporary string will be build out of the string literal, and temporaries can only bind to const lvalue references, or to rvalue reference.

These would work:

```
void func(const std::string&);
void func(std::string&&);
```

**Note**: Some compilers (notable VS) would accept your code because they allow to bind non-const lvalue references to temporaries as an "extension". But that is not standard C++, so you should avoid it if you want to write portable code. Also, using it means you have to find out with the vendor what the semantics are.

Comment: vc2008 allows it however. why?

Comment: @Ivars an infamous compiler "extension".

Comment: is `void func(const std::string&)` standard?

Comment: @Ivars also vc is happily replacing unknown return types by int, just to continue compiling and producing errors

Comment: @Ivars Do you mean standards-conforming C++? If so then yes.